# If $q(x)=x^2+1$, does $q^{\circ 1/2}$ exist?

Tags: functional-equations, function-and-relation-composition, fixed-point-iteration, fixed-points, fractional-iteration

I've been doing a lot of research about functional half-iteration, and I posed the following question to myself:

> Consider the function $q:\mathbb R\mapsto\mathbb R$ defined as
>   $$q(x)=x^2+1$$
>   Does $q^{\circ 1/2}$ exist? Does a continuous $q^{\circ 1/2}$ exist? What about a differentiable $q^{\circ 1/2}$?

It seems to me that $q^{\circ 1/2}$ exists, but I don't know how to **prove** that it exists (I certainly can't find it, since it's probably not an elementary function). So far, I've proven that if it exists and is continuous, then it must be bounded between $x$ and $q(x)$. My intuition tells me that a differentiable solution *probably exists*... but it may not be differentiable at $x=0$. I've worked out an "almost-graph" of a possible solution, but it's far from a rigorous proof:

[image]

Any ideas about how to attack this problem rigorously?

Comment: When you say $g = q^{\circ 1/2}$ you mean that $g(g(x)) = q(x)$?

Comment: @gt6989b Correct - by $q^{\circ 1/2}$, I mean *any function* such that $$q^{\circ 1/2}(q^{\circ 1/2}(x))=q(x)$$

Comment: I suppose it needs to be bounded below by $x^{\sqrt2}$

Comment: @gt6989b Perhaps something like that, since a functional half iterate of $x^2$ is $|x|^{\sqrt 2}$

Comment: You must have $\frac{d}{dx}g(g(x))|_{x=0}=g'(0)g'(g(0))=0$, so either $g'(0)=0$ or $g'(g(0))=0$; the latter is impossible if the function is convex (which seems a sensible restriction to impose) so you must have zero derivative (if it exists) at $x=0$, and so there _should_ be a differentiable solution at $x=0$...

Comment: Must $q^{\circ1/2}:\Bbb R\mapsto\Bbb R$, or may we restrict the domain to the positive reals?

Comment: This problem would be so much easier by replacing $x^2+1$ with $2x^2-1$ or $x^2-2$...

Comment: How so would they be easier? @JackD'Aurizio

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: they are conjugated with a Chebyshev polynomial, so they have an elementary functional square root, like $2\cos\left(\sqrt{2}\arccos\frac{x}{2}\right).$

Comment: Oh, that's interesting @JackD'Aurizio

Comment: Can we not do the same with $\cosh$ and $\operatorname{arccosh}$?

Comment: Oh, never mind. Doing so leads to an extended domain of your solution.

Answer (score 2):

I claim there is a continuous $f$ such that $f \circ f = q$.

Recursively define  $a_0 = 0$, $a_1 = 1/2 < 1 = q(a_0)$, and $a_{n+2} = q(a_{n})$.
Now start by taking $f$ to be any continuous increasing function from $[0,a_1]$ onto $[a_1,a_2]$, and define $f$ on $[a_n,a_{n+1}]$ for $n \ge 1$ by $f(x) = t^2+1$ where $x = f(t)$.
For negative $x$ we define $f(-x) = f(x)$.

If  $f(x) \sim 1/2 + \alpha x^2$ near $x=0$, 
we'll want $f'(1/2) = 1/\alpha$ to make $f$ differentiable.  Thus one 
possibility is $f(x) = 1/2 + (2-\sqrt{3}) x^2 + 4 \sqrt{3} x^4$ for $0 \le x \le 1/2$.

On the other hand, if I'm not mistaken an analytic $f$ seems not to be possible.

Comment: How might one show that $q^{\circ 1/2}$ cannot be analytic?

Comment: @Nilknarf: when the taylor series has diverging coefficients such that the radius of convergence is zero (which is -for example- known to be the case for the half-iterate of $\exp(x)-1$).